# lock a Procedure from running when parameter are same but allow when parameters are different

Tags: oracle, plsql, locking

How to prevent an procedure from running when parameters are same and allow when parameters are different. let me explain the exact problem

creating build up script

```
drop table datalock_test;
create table datalock_test
(year_ number) tablespace wad;
drop TYPE test_lock_type_arr;
drop TYPE test_lock_type;
create or replace TYPE test_lock_type AS OBJECT
                   (
                    year_ number
                    );
/                    
create or replace TYPE test_lock_type_arr IS TABLE OF test_lock_type
;
/
drop procedure insert_to_lock_test;
create or replace procedure insert_to_lock_test (p_year number)
as 
    l_arr test_lock_type_arr := test_lock_type_arr();
begin
select test_lock_type(year_) bulk collect into l_arr from (select p_year as year_ from dual) a
where not exists (select NULL from  datalock_test  b
where a.year_ = b.year_);
dbms_lock.sleep(15);
forall i IN l_arr.first .. l_arr.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
insert  into datalock_test
values
(
l_arr(i).year_
);

commit;
end;
/
truncate table datalock_test;
```

Normal Testing:-

Now if I run below code one record will be inserted

```
begin
insert_to_lock_test(p_year => 1999);
end;
/
```

Now If I rerun the above code again then NO record will be inserted.

Hard Testing:-

But If I run below then duplicate records will be inserted, which is not desirable.

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name => 'load1',
job_type => 'plsql_block',
job_action => 'begin
insert_to_lock_test(p_year => 2000);
end;',
enabled => true);
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name => 'load2',
job_type => 'plsql_block',
job_action => 'begin
insert_to_lock_test(p_year => 2000);
end;',
enabled => true);
end;
/
```

This duplicate is what I have to avoid.

Constraints :-

1. I cannot create unique Index nor Primary key's.
2. I cannot use any additional check and exists conditions.

What I have Tried :-

1. Exclusive lock was tried. But issue here is it has blocked below functionality as well. In below case parameters are different and so process should be able to run in parallel. Let me provide code on how this was done

Recreate Procedure as below

```
create or replace procedure insert_to_lock_test (p_year number)
as 
    l_arr test_lock_type_arr := test_lock_type_arr();
    lv_lockhandle VARCHAR2(500);
    lv_ret_code   PLS_INTEGER;
    lv_retcode    NUMBER;
    p_nm varchar2(200) := 'testlock';
begin
dbms_lock.allocate_unique(p_nm, lv_lockhandle);
    lv_retcode := dbms_lock.request(lockhandle=>lv_lockhandle, 
                                 lockmode => dbms_lock.x_mode);
select test_lock_type(year_) bulk collect into l_arr from (select p_year as year_ from dual) a
where not exists (select NULL from  datalock_test  b
where a.year_ = b.year_);
dbms_lock.sleep(15);
forall i IN l_arr.first .. l_arr.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
insert  into datalock_test
values
(
l_arr(i).year_
);

commit;
lv_ret_code := dbms_lock.release(lv_lockhandle);
end;
/
```

Post this lets run the code in parallel with same parameter

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name => 'load1',
job_type => 'plsql_block',
job_action => 'begin
insert_to_lock_test(p_year => 2000);
end;',
enabled => true);
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name => 'load2',
job_type => 'plsql_block',
job_action => 'begin
insert_to_lock_test(p_year => 2000);
end;',
enabled => true);
end;
/
```

No duplicates were inserted, only one record, which is desirable. But now issue is when we run below code

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name => 'load1',
job_type => 'plsql_block',
job_action => 'begin
insert_to_lock_test(p_year => 2020);
end;',
enabled => true);
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name => 'load2',
job_type => 'plsql_block',
job_action => 'begin
insert_to_lock_test(p_year => 2021);
end;',
enabled => true);
end;
/
```

Here for insert 2021 it takes too long and the delay is not desirable when the parameters are different.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve

Comment: Lets assume an SP1 is running with parameters a,b,c passed to it. Now if I try to run SP1 again with parameters a,b,c then it should not allow me but if I run SP1 with parameters p,q,r then it should run. This is the problem that I am trying to solve

Comment: Your missing the point of my question. Why don't you want them to run simultaneously. What issue are you trying to prevent? Please provide a working example of the problem you are having when run simultaneously

Comment: _"This is the problem that I am trying to solve"_  That is the _techinical_ problem you are trying to solve, as a solution to some _business_ problem.  Rather than waste time on an ill-conceived technical solution, you should state the _business_ problem and let the community work on the _best_ technical solution.  In short, you are asking a classic [x-y question](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: The busines process maight be very simple @EdStevens. The procedure performs different task based on the parameter value. The procedure may be called from several concurrent sessions, but *all executions must differ in the paramater value* - an attempt of a call with a paramater value that is currently running must be blocked.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - could be, but I don't think we can assume.  The OP needs to explain.

Comment: I have changed my question with a business problem. Let me know if its more clear to you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the setting of the paramater `timeout => 0`

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i1002556) says

> Number of seconds to continue trying to grant the lock. If the lock cannot be granted within this time period, then the call returns a value of 1 (timeout).

In zero seconds you may or may not get a *timeout*, so sometimes you are not blocked and sometimes you are.

Remove the `timout` parameter (and use the dafault `MAXWAIT`) *or* set it to some realistic value **and** check the response value - if is it `1` you got a timeout and must handle it. You mast handle all returns != 0.

*I general* you should always check the return code in the `request` and preferably also deploy some logic to detect hanging handles and release them (e.g. setting `release_on_commit`)

**Example**

Note the bit updated procedure.
Despite the removal of the `timeout` parameter I check the return code of the `request` function.

Finally I added the `p_wait` paramater, so I can shedule the *blocking* procedure with a long wait and the *testing* procedure without a wait and I can clearly see the behavior, which is also logged in the total elapsed time of the procedure.

All works as expected - see below

```
create or replace procedure testlockProc (p_nm varchar2, p_wait int default 0)
as
lv_lockhandle VARCHAR2(500);
    lv_ret_code   PLS_INTEGER;
    lv_retcode    NUMBER;
    request_failed EXCEPTION;
    lv_start DATE;
begin
    lv_start := sysdate;
    dbms_lock.allocate_unique(p_nm, lv_lockhandle);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' got handle '|| lv_lockhandle);
    lv_retcode := dbms_lock.request(lockhandle=>lv_lockhandle, /**timeout => 0,**/
                                 lockmode => dbms_lock.x_mode);
    if lv_retcode != 0 then
       raise request_failed;
    end if;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('request got REGEST response '|| lv_retcode);                                
    dbms_lock.sleep(p_wait);
    lv_ret_code := dbms_lock.release(lv_lockhandle);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('release got REGEST response '|| lv_retcode|| ' in ' || to_char( round((sysdate-lv_start)*24*3600))|| ' seconds');   
end;
/

-- session 1 - procedure blocks the parameter for 60 seconds
set serveroutput on
begin
testlockProc (p_nm => 'wow', p_wait => 60);
end;
/

got handle 1073741964107374196448
request got REGEST response 0
release got REGEST response 0 in 60 seconds


-- session 2  (procedure blocked due to identical parameter from session 1)

set serveroutput on
begin
testlockProc (p_nm => 'wow');
end;
/

got handle 1073741964107374196448
request got REGEST response 0
release got REGEST response 0 in 50 seconds

-- session 3 different parameter (handle) - runns immediately

set serveroutput on
begin
testlockProc (p_nm => 'wow23');
end;
/

got handle 1073741965107374196549
request got REGEST response 0
release got REGEST response 0 in 0 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you Marmite, the problem that I am trying to solve is. Lets assume an stored procedure SP1 is running with parameters a,b,c passed to it. Now if I try to run SP1 again with parameters a,b,c then it should not allow me , the lock should wait till the timeout. But if I run SP1 with parameters p,q,r then it should run it should be able to get the lock.

Comment: @sakeesh **step 1)** increate the timeout, to get timeout in zeor seconds is meaningless, **step 2)** check return code from `request` and raise exception if not equal zero. Than the locking will work as expected!

Comment: Thank you . This looks like is working